# PHP Beautifier / Formatter for cloud9 IDE

Tags: php, cloud9-ide, formatter, cloud9

In my [Cloud09 IDE](https://c9.io) I enabled the PHP setting *"Custom Code Formatter"*

But saving results in an Error: `No code formatter set for php: please check your project settings` there is no formatter predefined like with JS (`esformatter -i "$file"`) and google is of no help as well...

[image]

How do I use this setting?

How can I install a PHP formatter on Cloud9?

My only search revealed [this Pear package](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/) but it seems outdated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download `php-cs-fixer` https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer to your Cloud9 Workspace:

```
$ wget https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.0.0/php-cs-fixer.phar -O ~/php-cs-fixer
```

Put it in your `~/bin` directory:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin; mv ~/php-cs-fixer ~/bin
```

Make the file executable:

```
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/php-cs-fixer
```

Configure your IDE's Custom Code Formatter setting for PHP to use the formater with [whatever rules you want](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#usage):

```
php-cs-fixer fix "$file" --rules=@Symfony,@PSR2
```

That's how my `~/workspace/.c9/project.settings` file looks:

```
...
"php": {
    "@completion": true,
    "@formatOnSave": true,
    "@formatter": "php-cs-fixer fix \"$file\" --rules=@Symfony,@PSR2",
    "@path": ".:./vendor:/usr/local/bin"
},
...
```